# Getting a random result from foreach loop then doing foreach on the random results

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach

I am trying to do a foreach loop on an array of users then randomly select 1 user from every 5 and do a foreach loop again with the results to display there user id's, the following works up until the point of the second foreach which throws up an error, can anyone please advise on what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

```
$eligable_users = get_users(array(

  'meta_key' => 'eligable',
  'meta_value' => '0'

));


$user_chunks = array_chunk($eligable_users, 4);

foreach($user_chunks as $individual_user_chunk) {

    $random_result = array_rand($individual_user_chunk ,1);

    foreach($random_result as $user) {
        echo $user->ID . "</br>";
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting? What line does the error point to? What is the intent of the code? To randomly consume all of the array values? Can you provide sample of the actual `$eligable_users` array that's giving the error that reproduces the problem? See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help center, as well.

Comment: The error is : Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() , the code should get an array of users , divide the array into chunks of 5, get 1 random result out of each chunk of 5, then for each of the random results  do another foreach (foreach($random_result as $user)) to then echo the users user Id

Comment: So basically you just want 5 random user ids? I don't see a point in using two loops here.

Comment: I would like 1 random user id out of every chunk of 5

Comment: Why are you using `array_chunk(..., 4)` then? That gives you a chunk of 4 users, not 5.

Comment: So once I have a random result from the array : $random_result = array_rand($individual_user_chunk ,1); how do i then use this to extract the user ids

Comment: doesnt array chunk work as 0,1,2,3,4

Comment: No, the second argument to array chunk is a `size` not an offset. [See the manual for details](http://php.net/array-chunk).

Answer (score 0):

Your second loop doesn't actually make sense, because you'd be getting back a single result. When you have only one result from `array_rand()` it hands you back a key not an array.

> When picking only one entry, `array_rand()` returns the key for a random entry. Otherwise, an array of keys for the random entries is returned.
>
> [Source: php.net/array-rand](http://php.net/array-rand)

```
foreach($user_chunks as $individual_user_chunk) {

    $random_result = array_rand($individual_user_chunk ,1);

    echo $individual_user_chunk[$random_result]->ID . "<br>";

}
```

Comment: The above is almost there but the issue is when the array is broke into chunks it needs to read:

Array 1
result 1
result 2
result 3
result 4
result 5

Array 2
result 6
result 7
etc....

Where as the code above when randomizing array 2 for instance is randomising "result 1" when it should only randomize out of "result 6 , result 7" etc

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "_Array 1 result 1_", exactly. Can you elaborate on how that specifically relates to your code? You have no such stated requirements in your question.

Comment: Hopefully the above makes sense, thanks for your help by the way

Comment: No it doesn't, because that code doesn't do any such thing. Perhaps you have modified some aspect of your code or data that results in such a thing, but that's certainly not what my answer does.

Answer (score 0):

```
$chunks = array_chunk($eligable_users, 5);

foreach($chunks as $chunk) {
    $r = array_rand($chunk);
    $user = $chunk[$r];
    echo $user->ID . "</br>";
}
```